# regular expression to match exactly two words and not one of the the two

Tags: regex

I am wondering , how would i match the words "SAN JOSE" in a string "I love SAN JOSE but JOSE does not like it " so in essence i do not want the the word Jose to be matched but SAN JOSE should be matched together.

any ideas . thanks

Comment: Did you even try to solve this problem yourself? Read any tutorial on regex and you can solve this yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions in this case. You didn't specify a language, but most of them support basic string matching. Just search for `'san jose'` in case-insensitive mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need [a look-ahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions):

```
/san (?=jose)/
```

Comment: Asker specified that "SAN JOSE" be matched. With the look-ahead, it would only match "SAN".

Comment: He says "i do not want the the word Jose to be matched but SAN JOSE should be matched together." It's exactly what look-ahead assertions are for.

Comment: @Kolo You misunderstood the question

Comment: And how do you understand him?

Comment: Hrm. I see where that could be confused. Removed the down-vote, though I personally think that he means for the pair to be matched, but not "JOSE" alone. The question title and the first sentence seem to make that clear.

Comment: `match exactly two words and not one of the the two`

Comment: so i did try what kolo32 suggested and surprisingly the match found is only SAN out of SAN JOSE . I am using php and jdmichal's both comment is right . i want both the words to be matched for the regular expression

Answer (score -2):

You need to escape the space:
/SAN\ JOSE/

Comment: I eventually did it crudely...where in i checked for the existence of 2 word right after the first one using a nested if stmts

Comment: it took you 6 month to find it out?